# get html content of next element with a defined classname

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have problems with jQuery. If I have this code to fill tooltip div:

```
<div id="tooltip"></div>
<div class="tooltipMessage">Tooltip Message</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#id").html($("#tooltip").next(".tooltipMessage").html());
</script>
```

This works, the code takes the next element with classname `tooltipMessage` and fills element with id `tooltip`.

But if I have this code:

```
<div id="tooltip"></div>
<p>other element</p>
<div class="tooltipMesage">Tooltip Message</div>
```

`undefined` is returned.

How I can take HTML from the next element with the classname `tooltipMessage` if another element exists in the middle?

Comment: What is `$("#id")` supposed to be? Seems like you're referring to `#tooltip`, but you used a different selector.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you put all your elements inside a parent container and use find(selector) to fetch required elements? I think it's a much better approach and gives you some bulletproof isolation.

Regarding your question you can use [**nextAll('div.tooltipMesage')**](http://api.jquery.com/nextAll/) method to find required element.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved this problem before by ensuring that the id of the tooltip message has the same prefix as the the id it is bound to then then javascript can be written as

```
<div id="tooltip1"></div>
<div id="tooltip1Message" class="tooltipMessage>Tooltip Message</div>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
   $(".tooltipMessage").each(function(){
      var destId = $(this).attr("id").replace("Message","");
      $("#"+destId).html($(this).html());
    });
</script>
```

Then it doesn't matter how far apart the messages are, it will always find the appropriate message to bind to

Answer (score -1):

```
.next()  -Wii get the immediate sibling 
        // Here the immediate sibling of tooltip is  p tag..
        // So it returns a empty selector because it not a immediate 
        // sibling

<div id="tooltip"></div>
<p>other element</p>
<div class="tooltipMesage">Tooltip Message</div>
```

**EDIT**
So you need to use next twice to find it..

```
$("#id").html($("#id").next().next(".tooltipMessage").html());
```

OR

Use **.nextAll()**

```
$("#id").html($("#id").nextAll(".tooltipMessage").first().html());
```

Comment: Could I suggest [`nextAll('.tooltipMessage:first')`](http://api.jquery.com/nextAll/)? It's a little easier than trying to anticipate the number of siblings to traverse with chained `next()` method-calls.

Answer (score -4):

replace

```
$("#id").html($("#id").next(".tooltipMessage").html());
```

with

```
$("#id").html($("#id").find(".tooltipMessage").html());
```

`.next()` isn't looking for everything that is after in DOM , it is literally getting the next element `.find()` will work for you

EDIT:

I guess it's working , I read the question real fast and thought the HTML looked like this

```
<div id="tooltip">
   <p>other element</p>
   <div class="tooltipMesage">Tooltip Message</div>
</div>
```

`.find()` will work for all decendent elements `.siblings()` will work if you choose to keep the HTML the way it is in the question

Comment: Thanks dude, it works. In 9 minutes I can accept your answer. Again, thankyou very much.

Comment: @Carasuman: This works? If it works, then your HTML isn't the same as that in the question.

Comment: @user1689607 No, .find() its diferent to .next() and works to me...,send a negative for nothing its a bad attitude.

Comment: jQuery's `find()` method looks within the node(s) returned by the current selector to find descendants that match the selector passed to the `find()` method. Whereas in the HTML you posted `.tooltipMessage` is *not* a descendant of any element, and we still have no idea what element has the `id` of `#id` (since that's not in your posted HTML either).

Comment: According to the givem HTML if you use .find() you can't get the element , as .find()  searches for the children of the selector and not the siblings

Comment: @Carasuman: Of course they're different. That doesn't change the fact that `.find()` will not locate the `.tooltipMessage` when the `.tooltipMessage` is a sibling.

Comment: edited answer , sorry for confusion , I read the html in the question real fast , hope this helps

Comment: Why have you edited your question *after* you've been told that your answer works? (Despite the fact that the posted HTML couldn't possibly work with your previously-posted answer.) The fault lies in the question, not your answer (though it was, clearly, one heck of a guess...).

Comment: I edited to satisify all the people with 3 downvotes , and just so it will make sense to future people reading this